# Find pattern: sort and delete older files

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, date, sort

I want to delete old files and keep only the most recent from each file pattern based on the first five characters (`aa_te, bb_co, cc_co, dd_xy`) and the date and time in the file name.

Note:

All files have `.err.mm_dd_yyyy hr_mm_ss am/pm.csv` for the sorting.
Filename length may vary

Example: I have the below CSV files in my folder `c/test`

```
aa_te_bbc_207_mc_ghghgh.err.05_31_2021 7_15_04 am.csv
aa_te_ccd.err.05_30_2021 7_55_35 pm.csv
bb_co_ddee_354_m.err.06_15_2021 5_20_00 am.csv
bb_co_eeffff.err.06_15_2021 5_20_01 am.csv
cc_co_eeffyy_cc.err.04_10-2020 12_00_00 am.csv
dd_xy_eeffyyvv_cc.err.04_10-2020 12_00_00 am.csv
dd_xy_eeffyyvv_cc.err.04_10-2020 12_10_25 am.csv
```

What I expect remains of those afterwards:

```
aa_te_bbc_207_mc_ghghgh.err.05_31_2021 7_15_04 am.csv
bb_co_eeffff.err.06_15_2021 5_20_01 am.csv
cc_co_eeffyy_cc.err.04_10-2020 12_00_00 am.csv
dd_xy_eeffyyvv_cc.err.04_10-2020 12_10_25 am.csv
```

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you used YYYY-mm-dd date format, and 2-digit hours

Comment: I changed the file directory dir= c/test and, removed the echo rm and kept && " $search"  at last and run the code. There is no error message but the files are not removed at all. Am I missing something? Was it working for you? Will this code work for hundreds of files with out any change?

Comment: Is this a comment on @alecxs's answer?

Comment: never use code you don't fully understand

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDvEj.jpg

Answer (score 2):

delete "echo" `rm` in last line when okay for you

```
#!/bin/bash

# search dir
dir=./

# function conv PATTERN
conv() {
  # extract date from file name: 06_15_2021 5_20_00 am
  date=${1%.*}
  date=${date##*.}

  # sanitize date string: 06/15/2021 5:20:00-am
  date=${date//[^0-9AaPpMm]/-}
  date=${date/-//}
  date=${date/-//}
  date=${date/-/ }
  date=${date/-/:}
  date=${date/-/:}

  # print epoch time
  date --date="$date" +%s || return 1
  return 0
}

# search: *m.csv
for file in "$dir"*[Mm].[Cc][Ss][Vv]
  do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    # file name: bb_co_ddee_354_m.err.06_15_2021 5_20_00 am.csv
    file=${file##*/}
    # base name: bb_co_ddee_354_m
    name=${file%%.*}
    # suffix: ddee_354_m
    del=${name#*_}
    del=${del#*_}
    # short name = base name - _suffix: bb_co
    name=${name%_$del}
    # convert date
    date=$(conv "$file") || continue

    # search short name: bb_co_*m.csv
    for search in "${dir}${name}"_*[Mm].[Cc][Ss][Vv]
      do
        # delete older file
        date2=$(conv "${search##*/}") || continue
        [ "$date" -gt "$date2" ] && echo rm "$search"
    done
done
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131658/discussion-on-answer-by-alecxs-find-pattern-sort-and-delete-older-files).

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`, you could do:

```
#! /bin/zsh -

zmodload zsh/datetime
typeset -A latest=()
all=(
  *.err.*.csv(Nnoe['LC_ALL=C strftime -rs REPLY %m_%d_%Y_%I_%M_%S_%p ${${${REPLY:r}##*.err.}//[- ]/_}'])
)
for file in $all; do
  latest[$file[1,5]]=$file
done

keep=($latest)
echo rm -f -- ${all:|keep}
```

(to be run within the directory where the files are; remove `echo` (for dry-run) if that looks alright)

We sort the list of files by timestamp into `$all` using `zsh`'s `oe` glob qualifier which sorts (numerically (with `n`)) based on the value of `$REPLY` as returned by the code in `[...]`.

That code uses `strftime -r` (`strftime` in reverse which in effect is `strptime`) to convert the time stamp in the file name to the epoch time in seconds.

Then we loop on that list to record the latest file for each 5-character prefix in to the `$latest` associative array.

Then we use the `${a:|b}` array subtraction operator to remove the elements of `$all` that are not in `$keep` (itself containing the values of the `$latest` associative array).

That assumes all the `*.err.*.csv` files in the current directory are in the format you specified, though it will also accommodate filename where date elements are separated with `-`s instead of `_`s as seen in some of your samples (by converting the `-`s to `_`s using the ksh93-style `${var//pattern/replacement}` operator).

Comment: @alecxs, oh. I hadn't seen that. But then again, it contradicts the OP's specification.

Comment: @alecxs, I've updated the code so it converts the `-`s to `_`s prior to calling `strftime -r` in case it wasn't just typos in the OP's sample.