# sort and delete older file

Tags: files, find, date, sort, delete

How can I sort the below files based on the date and time inside the folder and delete the older ones and keep the most recent ones in Linux?

I just want to keep the latest one regardless of the actual date.
It does not matter if the most recent file is even a year old, I just want to keep that.

```
aa_zz_yuyubc_207_dc_ghgh.brr.01_30_2019 3_15_04 am.csv
aa_zz_chuucd.brr.04_30_2020 7_15_12 pm.csv
aa_zz_ddetr_354_m.brr.5_25_2021 03_28_00 am.csv
aa_zz_xyf.brr.6_05_2021 5_20_55 PM.csv
```

Expected result: only `aa_zz_xyf.brr.6_05_2021 5_20_55 PM.csv` remains:

Dates are in `<month>_<day>_<year> <hour>_<minute>_<second> am/pm` (12 hour format).

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us more details. Are you really using Unix? Which one? Do you maybe mean Linux instead? How can we know the age of the file? Should we try to parse the file's name, or should we take the age from the file system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find pattern: sort and delete older files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/677837/find-pattern-sort-and-delete-older-files)

Comment: @alecxs this question looks like a  simpler version of the other one, so they're not strictly speaking duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
echo rm -f -- *.brr.*.csv(nOe['
    LC_ALL=C strftime -rs REPLY "%m_%d_%Y %I_%M_%S %p" ${${REPLY:r}##*.brr.}
  '][2,-1])
```

(remove `echo` (for dry-run) if that looks alright)

We use `zsh`'s `Oe` glob qualifier to sort in reverse (*capital* `O`), numerically (with `n`) based on the value of `$REPLY` as returned by the code in `[...]`.

That code uses `strftime -r` (`strftime` in reverse which in effect is `strptime`) to convert the time stamp in the file name to the epoch time in seconds. Then, all we have to do is select only the 2<sup>nd</sup> to last (`[2,-1]`) to pass the `rm`, leaving only the one with the most recent timestamp.

Comment: @alecxs, the OP mentions nothing about any prefix that would have not to be ignored here. But if you wanted to only consider file names that start with `aa_zz`, it would just be a matter of changing `*.brr.*.csv` to `aa_zz*.brr.*.csv`

Answer (score -1):

Just use the xtime functions in find command

access time
creation time
modification time

example

```
find toto/ -name "*csv" -mtime +90 -exec rm {} \;
```

removes files only in toto/ how have a mtime > 90 days.

if you are sure you wanna keep only the last one whatever the date is corresponding or not to your needs (file name vs real dates of creation/modification/Access) of the file)

you might use something like to isolate the file to keep

```
 ls | sort -t_ -k5 -k4 -k3 | tail -1
```

here you need the exact reverse of it

```
number=$(ls | wc -l) # word cound by line
while read ; do  rm "${REPLY}" ; done < <(ls | sort -t_ -k5 -k4 -k3 | head -$(($number - 1)))
```

example :

```
/tmp/b$
 while read ; do  rm "${REPLY}" ; done < <(ls | sort -t_ -k5 -k4 -k3 | head -$(($number - 1)))
/tmp/b$
 ls
'aa_zz_ddetr_354_m.brr.5_25_2021 03_28_00 am.csv'
/tmp/b$
```

Comment: If the OP's file names represent their age, this command would remove all of them. In any case, the OP isn't asking how to delete old files but how to delete some and keep the newest.

Comment: so delete your post & write a correct one

Comment: Sorry? The only incorrect post here is your answer, is that what you want me to delete? I haven't posted anything.

Comment: explain your real need cause here we answer the question as it is and not the way tou thought it is : **you never explained you wanted a name-bases sorting instead of REAL time selection/sorting**

Comment: I am not the person who asked the question. All I know is what I can read in the question, and the question (which is not very clear, admittedly) says "How can I sort the below files based on the date and time inside the folder and delete the older ones and **keep the most recent ones**". And then there is even an expected output which shows that the file `aa_zz_xyf.brr.6_05_2021 5_20_55 PM.csv` should be kept. Your answer doesn't try to keep the newest files present, it just uses an arbitrary cutoff date, and it would actually remove the one file the OP wants to keep.

Comment: **most recent ones"** not **last one** exaclty what I answered to as a method not as the specific solution that is just sytupid in learning/understanding answers.   and find has a specific **newer** date option  and yes method is the good one to keep the N most recent ones **not the last one** AGAIN   then don't blame me about that this is just unseless and stupid

Comment: OK, you need to calm down now. I am not blaming you, I am simply pointing out that although the question is not clear, the _one thing_ that is clear is that the file `aa_zz_xyf.brr.6_05_2021 5_20_55 PM.csv` should be kept and your answer would delete it. You are answering "how can I delete files older than X" and the question here is "how can I delete some files but keep the newest". That's all. You can edit the answer or ignore me, up to you.

Comment: result is the same if comparison is chosen correctly  in both way we ask the question "how can I delete files older than X" & "how can I delete some files but keep the newest".as far nothing forbid X to be 1 day or even current day.   and I specified it was an example & not the exact solution   just admit it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find pattern: sort and delete older files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/677837/find-pattern-sort-and-delete-older-files)

Comment: you might add -n flag because columns missing leading zeros (even more funny on the linked duplicate there exist files with different delimiter than `_` for example *'cc_co_eeffyy_cc.err.04_10-2020 12_00_00 am.csv'*) and did you notice the time with am/pm suffix?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I just got access to a computer. These are a bit different than the linked duplicate. These files have the same file name prefix at the beginning and the only thing I was looking for is just to sort them with existing dates in the file name and keep only the most recent one regardless of the actual system date.